# How to make the cursor start at the beginning of its contents with a QLineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

Windows 7 SP1
MSVS 2010
Qt 4.8.4

This code:

```
#include <QTGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow*          window = new QMainWindow;
    QLineEdit*         line_edit = new QLineEdit;

    line_edit->setText("ABCDEFG");
    line_edit->setFixedSize(40,20);
    window->setCentralWidget(line_edit);
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Displays this:

[image]

Note that the "AB" is truncated and the cursor is at the end of the line edit.

I want it to display:

[image]

Here "FG" is truncated and the cursor is at the beginning of the line edit.

I've tried to setCursorPosition and cursorBackward to no avail. If I convert the text via the font metric's elidedText it will display from the beginning with the trailing "...". But I don't want to do that.

Question: Is there a way to make the cursor to start at the beginning of its contents after displaying a QLineEdit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting cursor position to 0 just after setting text should work just fine. At least it does here on Linux, Qt 4.8.3.

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow*          window = new QMainWindow;
    QVBoxLayout*          layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    QLineEdit*         line_edit = new QLineEdit;

    line_edit->setText("ABCDEFG");
    line_edit->setFixedSize(40,20);
    line_edit->setCursorPosition(0);
    layout->addWidget(line_edit);
    window->setCentralWidget(line_edit);
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I found my problem in my larger program: I was setting the cursor position before I was setting the text. Setting it after setting the text solve my problem. Again, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

[`setCursorPosition(0)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#cursorPosition-prop) works fine for me:

```
// ...
line_edit->setFixedSize(40,20);
line_edit->setCursorPosition(0);
// ...
```

(Windows, VC++2010, Qt5.0.0)

Comment: @Jakob Leben You are absolutely right. I apologize. I am having this problem in a much larger program where setCursorPostion did not work. I melted the issue down to a simple program for illustration but neglected to test the setCursorPostion there. I'll need to analyze further why this isn't working in my larger program. Thanks!

Comment: I found my problem in my larger program: I was setting the cursor position before I was setting the text. Setting it after setting the text solved my problem. Again, thanks for the help!